# Java Selenium executing a Javascript that deletes the browser IndexedDB Inbox

Tags: indexeddb, selenium-java, javascriptexecutor

I have created a Java selenium automated test suite that tests a progressive web app. I want to delete the browser IndexDB in one of my tests. To do this I planned to create a 'JavascriptExecutor' onject in my Java Selenium test class. This is my code:-

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver(); 
js.executeScript("window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase('test-db')");
```

When I run my test the browsers indexedDB is not deleted. There are no errors are thrown in the console either. I have tried running the following command manually in the browser console to make sure that the command works, and it does delete the indexedDB:-

```
window.indexedDB.deleteDatabase('test-db')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hope you made sure that the page got loaded and indexedDB was available before you try to delete them. Its not like, you try to delete a db that doesn't exist and then it gets created.